# Install Kubuntu with btrfs

Tags: kubuntu, system-installation, ubiquity, btrfs

I don't have much space on the hard drive, so I was considering using btrfs for my hard drive. I'm aware that btrfs is not stable yet, but I'm interested in installing Kubuntu with it anyway. How can I install Kubuntu using btrfs partition? I would prefer a solution that doesn't require me to change the partition format after installation.

I've read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs, but it was last edited two releases ago, and I'm not sure if the content applies to Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same procedure as for any other Ubuntu-based system:

### disclaimer

*I've never used btrfs RAID. The solution is tested only on single-volume btrfs root partitions*

---

1. Make sure, there are no `/@` and `/@home` subvolumes on the candidate for root.
2. Launch the Ubuntu installer, and choose *something else* when it asks you about disk partitioning.
3. Mark your btrfs partition as root filesystem, but **don't let the installer reformat it**.
4. Arrange all the other partitions as you like. I always choose to use external `/boot` partition on `gpt` systems, so I can later migrate into something more advanced (e.g. `bcache`) or whatever. (On `gpt` you can have as many partitions as you want, so I see no real drawback of using dedicated `/boot`.)
5. Finish the installation.

The installer will make the `@` and `@home` subvolumes for you. Later you can rename them into something different - just be sure you also update the new name on both `/etc/fstab` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04, Mint 16, Mint 15, Ubuntu 13.10 and Ubuntu 13.04.